# Getting/extract month and year from full date (datetime)

Tags: oracleforms

I had column with date datatype I am trying to extract the month and year 
from full date to calculate total sales within month at year 
but I'm getting error that expecting , ; when find from I test the query below 
within toad and its works fine in anyway that query will not give me what exactly i want the result in toad was only month and I need my calculation based on on month and year

I tried trunc but the result will be DD-MM-YYYY

`To_char` works at database column but not worked out with the text_item at forms builder

so how to let that query works and is there a way to extract month and year ?

```
SELECT NVL(SUM(TOTAL_PRICE),0) 
  INTO :DUMMY.M_TOTAL_ORDERS
  FROM ORDERS 
  WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ORDER_DATE)= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that you're getting an error but you don't tell us what error.  You tell us that the query "works fine" but that it doesn't do exactly what you want.  A test case with sample data and expected results would be quite helpful.

My guess is that you want

```
SELECT NVL( SUM(total_price), 0)
  FROM orders
 WHERE trunc( order_date, 'MM' ) = trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )
```

which I would expect to return the result that I think you want.  But it wouldn't be able to use a regular index on `order_date` (you could create a function-based index on `trunc(order_date, 'MM')` that could be used).

```
SELECT NVL( SUM(total_price), 0)
  FROM orders
 WHERE order_date BETWEEN trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ) AND sysdate
```

would also work (assuming `order_date` is always less than `sysdate`) and would allow you to use an index on `order_date` if one existed.

If that is not what you're after, posting a reproducible test case would be very helpful.

Comment: select trunc( sysdate, 'MM' ) from dual result will be 5/1/2015 while I need to retrieve my data according to 5/2015 (MM/YYYY) and the query above will give YYYY only the error was  Error 103 at line ... at each line contains extract keywords I think forms 6i don't support it while my database is 11g

Comment: @xXghostXx - I'm not following the concern.  ` trunc( sysdate, 'MM' )` returns May 1, 2015 at midnight.  But `trunc( order_date, 'MM' )` also returns May 1, 2015 at midnight for any row where the `order_date` is between May 1, 2015 at midnight and May 31, 2015 at 23:59:59.  So the equality condition will hold for all orders with an `order_date` at any point in the month.  That's my best guess at what you want.  If my guess is incorrect, a test case would be very helpful.